# How to merge a branch without deleting local files?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Let's say I have a repository with a main branch `master` and 3 files:

- `fileA` [tracked]
- `fileB` [tracked]
- `fileC` [tracked]

I create a new branch `test` and I delete `fileB`

Now I want to go back to `master` and merge `test` into it, but I don't want `fileB` to be deleted, just "untracked" from git:

- `fileA` [tracked]
- `fileB` [untracked]
- `fileC` [tracked]

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: One approach would be: `git cherry-pick -n` the `HEAD` commit of `test` into `master`, resolve any merge conflicts, then unstage the deletion of `fileB` using `git reset fileB`.

Comment: I've never used [git-cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). I tried this but couldn't get it to work. This happend to me a few times now and I've always dealt with it "manually". In the end I used the naive approach, which seems to work, and I'll explain in an answer for future self reference.

Answer (score 0):

The "naive" approach worked as I expected.

First I copy the contents of the folder away to a temporary location. Then I do the merge. Then I copy back the old contents over the merged ones and finally I discard the changes.

The sentences to run are (being on the repository root, on the branch `master`):

```
git archive -o /tmp/temporary_repo_archive.zip HEAD
git merge test
unzip /tmp/temporary_repo_archive.zip
git reset --hard
rm /tmp/temporary_repo_archive.zip
```